# Why is "sudo unmount" required for unmounting an sshfs-mount if it was mounted without sudo privilges?

Tags: filesystems, sudo, sshfs, fuse, umount

I have an sshfs FUSE filesystem mounted in `~/mountpoint`. I tried `umount mountpoint` and `diskutil unmount mountpoint` (on a Mac here) and both failed. I used `sshfs -o IdentityFile=<key> user@hostname:/home/<user> ~/mountpoint`; none of that required sudo.

Why, then, do unmount it do I need sudo privilges?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because umount only allows root to unmount regular filesystems.

You can, however, unmount any FUSE filesystem (inclusing sshfs) without using sudo:

```
fusermount -u mountpoint
```

Comment: yes, but I have no command `fusermount` installed; I believe it is linux-specific. But thanks - I didn't know umount was sudo-only